# "swrlb:contains" built-in for named individuals

Tags: owl, protege, swrl

How to check whether a named individual of an ontology contains some particular string? For example consider the following rule:

```
swrlb:contains(namedIndividual:mwf,"m")-> contains(namedIndividual:mwf,"m")
```

Comment: Like this: `hasAddress(?x, ?address) ^ swrlb:contains(?address, "@") -> hasEmail(?x, ?address)`. Or do you want to treat URIs as strings and search in them?

Comment: Yes, I want to treat URI's as strings and search in them.